# How to use a class field to keep track of a list

Tags: python

So I am stuck on a problem while trying to code a game of Battleship. I am just curious on the most efficient way to use fields. For example:

```
class Board:
      def __init__(self, size):
          self.size = size
          self.board = [[.]] 
class Ship:
      def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name # ignore name 
         self.ship = board[0][0]
```

The main goal I am trying to achieve is obtaining self.board within the Ship class. Is it possible to just reference self.board even though they are two different classes?

Comment: Short answer: Yes you can. Long versoin: Depends completely on your use-case

Comment: How he can we use self to define private functions and variables

Comment: That is where I am kind of lost. How can I call self.board in class Ship? If that helps clarify my question more.

Comment: Actually, do you really need to reference the board in the ship class? Yes, you can, but what for? I would expect that you will need a property of Board class to hold ships on the board and which squares are occupied.

Comment: I would like to reference it because I need to print out the ship that is within the list. So for example, if there is a battleship in it, the list will have four 'B's within it. Then, I need class Ship to print out 'BBBB'. This can be hardcorded, but whenever class Board must update the list to change a 'B' to an 'X' (to show it has been hit), class Ship must print out 'BBBX'. Side note, any 'B' can be shot, this was just an example if one of them got shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a new instance of the `Board` class within the `Ship` class??

```
class Board:
  def __init__(self, size):
    self.size = size
    self.board = [[43,2346]] 

class Ship:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.OMG = Board(49035093)
    self.name = name # ignore name 
    self.ship = self.OMG.board[0][0]
```

And get it like:

```
>>> a=Ship('wasif')
>>> a.ship
43
```

Comment: This works actually thank you (: I guess now I am stuck on how to update self.board in Board and how to keep track of that within Ship.

Comment: I don't know why it is downvoted but I have voted it